# Is there a better way to get many to many associations records' propertity list in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have created two models(User, Project) with many to many associations and create a association table(ProjectUser):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :email
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :address
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
end

class ProjectUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

With association specified, I can get a user's projects like this:

```
projects = User.find('user_id').projects
```

While if I just want project name list, is there any method works like this:

```
# This will get NoMethod error
project_names = User.find('user_id').projects.names
```

Now I do it like this:

```
project_names = User.find('user_id').projects.map {|project| project.name}
```

I'm wondering is there any syntactic sugar to do like this :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the names you should be able to do a join on the project_users table and simply pluck the names:

```
project_names = Project.joins(:project_users).where(user_id: 'user_id').pluck(:name)
```

If you already have the user then I'd just do it through the association like you have.

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
project_names = @user.projects.pluck(:name)
```

More info on pluck [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)